# Compiling Haskell code with Cygwin

Tags: haskell, cygwin

I am reading "Learn you a Haskell for great good", and have reached the chapter on I/O actions. I am using Windows, and have downloaded GHCi and WinGHCi.

I'm trying to compile a simple program and have saved a file on emacs as `helloworld.hs` with `main = putStrLn "hello, world"` in it.

The book says

> Open your terminal, navigate to the directory where `helloworld.hs` is located, and enter the following:
>
> ```
> $ ghc --make helloworld
> ```

I am using Cygwin.

If I put `$ ghc --make helloworld` I receive `target 'helloworld' is not a module name or a source file`. Do I have to write some specific commands in Cygwin prior to writing `$ ghc --make helloworld`?

How can I navigate to where helloworld.hs is, or enter the full path to the file?  It is in the Local disk (C:), emacs-25.3_1-x86_64 , bin
[image]

Comment: Type `cd emacs-25.3_1-x86_64` then press Enter, then type `cd bin` and press Enter. This will yield you to the desired folder.

Comment: Thank you :) And then what? `ghc --make helloworld` ?

Comment: That works :) So in future `cd emacs-25.3_1-x86_64`, `cd bin` and then `ghc --make <file name>`

Comment: Suggestion for future questions: post errors and output from the console as text, and not as images -- it is easier for everyone. (You can copy and paste text in the console with Ctrl+Insert and Shift+Insert respectively.)

Answer (score 2):

From the screen shot, your current working directory is `/cygdrive/c`, and as the `ls` command shows, there's no file there called `helloworld.hs`.

I think you'll need to either navigate to where `helloworld.hs` is, or perhaps, alternatively, you may be able to enter the full path to the file.

You can use the `cd` command to change directory.

Comment: How do I navigate to it? It is in the Local disk (C:), emacs-25.3_1-x86_64 , bin

Comment: @user65526 Usually, in e.g. Bash, `C:` is `/c`, but looking at the contents of `/cygdrive/c`, that looks a lot like a `C:` drive. Use `cd` to change directory, just like you'd do in the Windows Command Prompt.